# Knowing which page opened using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page.In that i used 3 images with a tag i am navigating page. Is it possible to know which image clicked in newly opened html page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, have the link the image uses have a query string or hash tag, like so:

```
<a href="YourSite.com/YourPage.htm?Image=1"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

And then pull that like so:

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
if (getQuerystring("Image")=="1"){ ... }
```

Query string code from [javascript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609559/javascript-query-string) and from [Blogging Developer](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx) originally

Answer (score -1):

yes using javascript.

you can with JS + Ajax then you can insert an entry in Database on image onclick event.

Give us more detail/code if you want to know more about this solution.

Comment: -1, I'd never recommend anyone doing this. Slow and not certain you always get the right referral image. Sorry...